# linking style.css to header.html

Tags: html, css

I have a folder called myWebsite. In this myWebsite folder there is a index.php document and an includes folder. Inside the includes folder there is a style.css and header.html document (which will be linked to each php page in the myWebsite folder) I am working on linking the style.css document to the header.html document. Both the style.css and header.html are in the same includes folder. Why is it making me do includes/style.css in order to link them? they are in the same folder and I should be able to style.css. If my header.html was in the myWebsite folder then that makes sense since you need to go inside the includes folder but here I am already in the includes folder

Didn't work to link both unless I did includes/style.css. Why doesn't it work just to do style.css since they are both in the same folder